# axios property get of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a class inside src/lib/lib.ts

```
export default class LibClass implements LibInterface {
   someFunc () {
       ...
       const httpResponse = await (this as any).$axios.$get(url)
       return httpResponse.data
   }
}
```

and inject it on the component via

```
import { Inject } from 'inversify-props'
import LibInterface from '@/lib/lib'
@Component
export default class Test extends Vue {
    @Inject()
    private libCLass!: LibInterface
}
```

and Im getting `TypeError: Cannot read property '$get' of undefined`

I already defined the @nuxtjs/axios on tsconfig.json

```
"types": [
  "@nuxtjs/axios",
]
```

I used `$axios` on `LibClass` to be able to separate my axios calls and just call it on my components using dependency injection `(inversify.js)`

any idea on how can I fix this?

Comment: edited @EstusFlask

Comment: The question still doesn't mention how LibClass is used and why you expect $axios to be there. If you inject it with Inversify, please, provide all relevant code. *@nuxtjs/axios on tsconfig.json* isn't supposed to help, it only affects TS types, while you get runtime error, this means that $axios is really not there.

Comment: Well, I don't have any problem on injecting on vue components thats why i did not include it.

Comment: Im using nuxt community axios. I just need to call that function on my component thats why I needed $axios there. I needed to separate my axios call to make code more readable. I followed the documentation and I thought it is expected that the this.$axios will make it global and I can be able to access it anywhere

Comment: It is not a component. It is a class that will be injected on my component :/.

Comment: How exactly will it be injected? Please, provide actual code where LibClass is instantiated that could help to understand your problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You've seen your own code and know what you talk about. Other users didn't. Currently it seems that you're fighting windmills because it's easier to access and extend Axios instance with a plugin, https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend

Comment: check the edited

Comment: I see. The problem is very specific to Nuxt+Inversify. `@nuxtjs/axios` doesn't play well with Inversify. You may want to create Axios instance with Inversify instead and inject it with `@Inject` everywhere. I suppose a workaround for your case would be `LibClass.prototype.$axios = $axios` inside a plugin. Since you're hard-coding LibClass this way, this defies the purpose of DI a bit.